# Bootstrap Rollover Div links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im looking to make a div with some content and when the mouse roll overs the div, three links would appear in the div. Like so:

[image] [image]

I'v have been searching through Stack and google and cannot find a way to implement this with three different ahref tags.

### html

```
.container
  .col-md-4
    .pdf-thumb-box
      a(href='#')
        .pdf-thumb-box-overlay
          span.fa-stack.fa-lg
            i.fa.fa-square-o.fa-stack-2x.pdf-thumb-square
            i.fa.fa-eye.fa-stack-1x.pdf-thumb-eye
        img.img-responsive(src='http://lorempixel.com/400/300/technics/')
    .vertical-social-box

  .col-md-4
    .pdf-thumb-box
      a(href='#')
        .pdf-thumb-box-overlay
          span.fa-stack.fa-lg
            i.fa.fa-square-o.fa-stack-2x.pdf-thumb-square
            i.fa.fa-eye.fa-stack-1x.pdf-thumb-eye
        img.img-responsive(src='http://lorempixel.com/400/300/technics/')
    .vertical-social-box

  .col-md-4
    .pdf-thumb-box
      a(href='#')
        .pdf-thumb-box-overlay
          span.fa-stack.fa-lg
            i.fa.fa-square-o.fa-stack-2x.pdf-thumb-square
            i.fa.fa-eye.fa-stack-1x.pdf-thumb-eye
        img.img-responsive(src='http://lorempixel.com/400/300/technics/')
```

### css

```
.pdf-thumb-box
  display: inline-block !important
  position: relative !important
  overflow: hidden

.pdf-thumb-box-overlay
  visibility: hidden
  opacity: 0
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.5s,opacity 0.5s linear

.pdf-thumb-box a
  color: transparent
  &:hover .pdf-thumb-box-overlay
    visibility: visible
    opacity: 1
    transition-delay: 0s
    text-align: center
    position: absolute
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.58)
    color: #fff
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)

.pdf-thumb-box-overlay span
  margin: auto
  position: absolute
  top: 0
  left: 0
  bottom: 0
  right: 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

## [> DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/exbhjbfg/)

### HTML

```
<div id="rollover">
    <div id="container">
        <a class="link" href="#">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/X2faVAp.png"></a>
        <a class="link" href="#">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cd4iQS1.png"></a>
        <a class="link" href="#">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ioxt4re.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#rollover {
    width: 170px;
    height: 55px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #7FFFD4;
}
#container {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s linear; /* vendorless fallback */
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s linear; /* opera */
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s linear; /* IE 10 */
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear; /*safari and chrome */
}
#container:hover {
    opacity: 100;
}
img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```